# JSession id getting created even if session set to false

Tags: java, jsp

I understand that a jsp automatically creates a session but when set to false using page import, its not created.But when i try printing the session id cookie even if the session has been set to false, I don't get a null value.Instead I get a long SessionId value.

I wonder how is this possible.

Comment: Are you sure that all the JSPs you executed before executing the one with session = false also have their session set to false? And that no servlet or filter asked for a session?

Comment: yes infact this is the first jsp..but just for knowledge ..had it been an intermediate jsp then settin it to false shall discontinue the session and in that jsp we shall not be able to retrieve sessionid ryt????

Comment: No. Once the session is created, a cookie is sent to the browser, and it sends it with every request. session = false allows not creating a session if none exist yet. If the session exists, it exists.

Comment: Ok ..i got it ..how do I disable the sessionid cookie that had got set earlier??